# Find out which part of a querySelector matched a given element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any possibility to find out which part of a querySelector matched a specific element in the DOM?

Let's say you have the following query:

'h1,h2,h3,h4.custom-bg,div'

If you use document.querySelectorAll, how can I backtrace the fragment of my query that was responsible for finding the element in the DOM?

Comment: Please provide more specifics about use case. You will need to test against individual selectors yourself

Comment: Split selector into parts and use `Element.matches()`

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Element.matches`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches), which has a [reasonable support](http://caniuse.com/#search=Element.matches) as of now.

> The [`Element.matches()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.matches) method returns true if the element would be
>   selected by the specified selector string; otherwise, returns false.

You would use something like this

```
var str = 'h1,h2,h3,h4.custom-bg,div';
[].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll(str), function(elm){
   var slctrMatched = str.split(",").filter(elm.matches);
   console.log(slctrMatched.join(" "));
});
```

We are making use of `Array.forEach` but more importantly, `Array.filter`, which is passed `Element.matches` method, so it filters out the selectors, returning an Array, which we are outputting to console by joining it by `Array.join`

Comment: Thank you. Interesting solutions. I thought there might be a backtracing mechanism.

Comment: why not just split the filter before calling `querySelectorAll` and call the `querySelectorAll` using a loop for each "selector piece"?